# read teaxt area value on next page. storing values for the next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, textarea

I have a textarea and i want to get the input from it and onthe next page use the input.

I guess i need to store the input value somwhere to be used on the second page. Is there a way to do it without plugins? if not, how else can i do this? Please provide examples if possible.

```
<textarea id="map" rows="3" cols="43"></textarea>
<button type="button" onClick="save()">Save</button>

function save() { //code to save info to be used on next page}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can improve the behavior doing client-side checking with **localStorage**, or you can use **sessionStorage**

Example:

**ON PAGE 1 do this:**

```
 <textarea id="map" rows="3" cols="43"></textarea>
 <button type="button" onClick="save()">Save</button>

 <script type = "text/javascript">

 function save() { 

 var someText = document.getElementById("map").value;
 sessionStorage.setItem('myvar', someText);
 window.location.href = "page2.html";
 }
```

**NOW on PAGE 2 (page2.html) to get the value simply do this:**

```
 <script>
 var data = sessionStorage.getItem('myvar');

  alert(data);

 </script>
```

Basically whatever you type in textarea (on page 1) will be available in Page 2.

Comment: Hello and Thank you Henry, Can you please show me using my code.

Comment: You're welcome :). I'm updating my answer so you can understand it better.